# ASP.Net website hanging in Chrome

Tags: asp.net

I've an ASP.Net site that occasionally won't load just after it's been built - but only in Chrome.  If I load it in Firefox it's fine - and actually after it's loaded in Firefox it's then fine in Chrome.

The error in Chrome is just "This webpage is not available".  I could leave it a few minutes and it might start working randomly.

There's no activity going on in the process - I can't attach and pause a debugger

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you publishing and then navigating there, or is this when debugging the project?

Comment: Within `Chrome Developer Tools` console tab do you see any errors?

Comment: Alas no errors in developer tools.  And just after publishing and navigating there.  If the site falls asleep it happens as well